# How many bakers on currently baking on tezos?

Tags: baking, baking-node

Is this the right URL to answer this question?

https://tzscan.io/charts_bakers

So currently there are 219 bakers? Also is there a way to get the number of distinct bakers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number of bakers on the tezos network for the current cycle is often underreported.

In tezos every node validates each block, whereas bakers produce blocks (baking) and also endorse the blocks of other bakers.

The link to tzscan in your question is only the bakers that baked a block, but many more bakers exist which endorsed blocks (and either missed their baking opportunity or weren't assigned rights to bake). Even more bakers exist that for various reasons didn't receive any rights in the current cycle.

For the most recent cycle 145, the total number of bakers that baked blocks is 222.

The total number of bakers that received rights to either bake or endorse is 463 (https://bakendorse.com/#/cycles/145/projected_stats).

And the total number of registered bakers with or without rights is 554 (https://arronax-beta.cryptonomic.tech).

Additionally, the total number of validating nodes is far higher and well over 2000. Each baker usually runs multiple public and private nodes with a minimum of 1 node per baker; and there are many more network nodes which aren't affiliated with bakers.